# SQL Stored Procedure Debugging in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I am attempting to debug a stored procedure in VS2010 using the Server Explorer and the "Step into stored procedure" menu item command.

The issue I am having is that when I right click on the stored procedure, the only options I have are Copy, Refresh and Properties. Is there anything I need to do to make the "Step into stored procedure" option appear?

- SQL Debugging is enabled in the project properties for good measure.
- The Step into option is available in my vs2005 installation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the server / database to Visual Studio 2010 [Server Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x603htbk.aspx).

Then you'll be able to debug stored procedures.

Comment: The server has been added to the server explorer. And I can navigate to the stored procedure. When I right click on the stored procedure I am given 3 options...Copy, Refresh and Properties. The 'Step into stored procedure' as well as the 'Execute' command are absent.

Comment: Just curious, most defiantly not an answer, but can you put a break point into the stored procedure if you can get it from VS?

Comment: @user633084 I know it's a little outdated, but have you tried following whats on this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316549 ?

Comment: Chris, I can not set a breakpoint, there is no way of opening the stored procedure to do so. Double clicking it expands the parameter list, but does nothing else.

Comment: user633084 , I have seen the article, the issue is the menu items it is suggests using are not available for some reason.

Comment: @user633084 That's weird, what version it is that you're using?

Comment: @swestner I mean, Professional, or what?

Answer (score 0):

This should work using VS10 Pro and MsSQL10R2, and have set up the MsSQL instance where the stored procedure lives in Server Explorer so that VS10 can connect to the same server instance your program connects to to execute its SP.  Opening the Server Explorer and locating the SP, then right-clicking its name in the tree-view gives you this option.

Previous MsSQL versions supported SP debugging only in tools like Query Analyser, and then by standalone execution rather than as part of a running mixed-platform application program.

In VS10 one can also debug stored procedures on MsSQL9 this way, by standalone execution, by opening a SQL window, right-clicking and picking "Connection" from the pop-up window, and connecting to the server instance on which you wish to execute the query or SP.  In the PL/SQL script representing the guts of the SP one can then set breakpoints.

(Note that this started out as a WAG:  I've done it before and happend across this question while surfing for information to elicit enough recall that I didn't have to re-enact the entirety of the original train of thought.  Then I revised the answer as I went along checking that what I thought worked worked.)

Comment: Wives And Girlfriends? What might a WAG be in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to script out the stored procedure and open the sql file into your local or server SQL Server with Management Sudio? You will be able to set some PRINT flags and debug as per your needs. Hope this workaround works!.

Answer (score 0):

check that you use data provider: ".Net Framevork DataProvider for SQL Server"